# Is const reference to a global constant good practice?

Tags: c++

Trying to figure out how to efficiently and safely reference global custom type constants that are initialized at compile time. I want to avoid copying of Foo as I will be creating a lot of Bar instances and Foo is a bit more complicated than shown here. Keeping a const reference from Bar to Foo appears to be safe (or is it?) but at the same time I don't know how to prevent the "badBar" usage if possible. Any suggestions?

```
class Foo
{
    int a_, b_;
public:
    constexpr Foo(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
};

inline constexpr Foo kFoo{1, 2};

class Bar
{
    const Foo& foo_;
public:
    Bar(const Foo& foo) : foo_(foo) {}
    const Foo& foo() { return foo_; }
};

int main() {
    Bar goodBar(kFoo);
    Bar badBar(Foo(3, 4)); // ouch
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you make the `Bar` constructor take a `const Foo *` instead of a `const Foo &`, then at least the shlemiel coders of the world will have to work a bit harder at shooting themselves in the foot with it, as they won't be able to (easily) pass in a temporary object as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, keeping a reference to globally defined constant variable is safe as it will always be valid.

You can just initialize the member directly:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int a_, b_;
public:
    constexpr Foo(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
};

inline constexpr Foo kFoo{1, 2};

class Bar
{
    const Foo& foo_=kFoo;
};
```

The rest of the world does not have to know it exists and makes the ctor of `Bar` simpler.

Although it feels slightly redundant, anywhere you can write `foo_`, you can also write `kFoo`. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Good point about preventing passing foo from the outside. I will have class hierarchy rooted at Bar, so I can pass references to constants from derived class constructors to the same effect, and Bar's constructor will be protected.

Comment: Oh, and you want to somehow restrict the foos that can be passed? Or how do you define what is `badBar`? Just a note, do not try to make the code 100% fool-proof, there is no upper bound on ingenuity of fools. If the ctor is protect and it's documented what it can accept, that should be enough. IF you really want and are able to make `Bar`'s ctor `constexpr`, you can add bunch of `static_assert` e.g. comparing the parameter to addresses to known constants.

Comment: The badBar was just a hypothetical example someone passing a reference to a temporary which I now realize is not applicable to my situation. I'm in control of the class hierarchy and will make sure references to defined constants are passed to the Bar's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an rvalue constructor to discard rvalue arguments.

```
class Bar
{
    const Foo& foo_;
public:
    Bar(const Foo& foo) : foo_(foo) {}
    Bar(Foo &&) = delete; // <-- rvalue constructor
    const Foo& foo() { return foo_; }
};
```

Comment: Can still be risky. e.g when returning Bar created in a function from a local Foo

Comment: @user2717954 In most cases it will be caught by [automatic moving](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes).

Comment: @xskxzr, why do you mean by "caught"? Even after the rvalue ctor is deleted this compiles and runs but problematic as far as I can tell. I've been pondering it for some time and tend to think it is better err on the side of caution and copy Foo in those cases where I can't initialize members directly from the constant inside the ctor.
```
Bar createBar()
{
    Foo lFoo(4, 5);
    Bar bb(lFoo);
    return bb;
}

int main() {
    Bar badBar = createBar(); // ouch?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @VladG Maybe you want to delete the copy/move constructor of `Bar`. Otherwise if you construct a `Bar` `a` from another `Bar` `b`, then after `b` is destructed, `a` will become unsafe.